# Can I run an independent instance of a Flatpak app?

Tags: flatpak

Can I run an independent, isolated instance of an arbitrary Flatpak app? In other words, the second instance won't share local resources (say, a cache) with the first instance.

Comment: This sounds theoretical; how far did you get?

Comment: This is clearly a Linux question. Why was it moved here?